# Partition unreachable in a HDD which was part of a RAID 1 cluster

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, raid1

I am out of options here because of my lack of knowledge and I seriously need a hand in order to get my data back. Yes, I did the mistake of trusting RAID system too much...

Here is what happened: One of the 2 HDD in a RAID 1 failed, but no data was readable.  The NAS said that the volume was unaccessible. I thought maybe that was because of the broken drive so I replaced it with another one,  but without success. I decided to remove them all, reset the NAS with 2 new 2TB hdd and plan to read the sane 500g drive later to get my data back and put it in the server freshly configured.

So I bought a SATA to USB box and I am trying to read in a linux laptop with mdadm.
The closest I was able to be to my data was mount the RAID with  mdadm --assemble --scan. The resulting volume is a 2,1gb one with `etc`, `user` and `lost+found` folders. As you can see in the output below, the partition with the data is there, just unreachable.

Anyone can help me here ? Or redirect me to the right place ? Or am I definitely screwed ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

**Relevant output**

$$ fdisk -l

```
Disque /dev/sda : 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs
Disk model: 00AAKX-001CA0   
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 33553920 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : gpt
Identifiant de disque : C8CCF56D-AA4F-4AD3-AE23-1D626048D753

Périphérique   Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Type
/dev/sda1       2048    524287    522240   255M Système de fichiers Linux
/dev/sda2     524288   4718591   4194304     2G RAID Linux
/dev/sda3    4718592   8912895   4194304     2G RAID Linux
/dev/sda4    8912896 976773119 967860224 461,5G RAID Linux


Disque /dev/md126 : 2 GiB, 2144337920 octets, 4188160 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 33553920 octets


Disque /dev/md0 : 2 GiB, 2144337920 octets, 4188160 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 33553920 octets
```

$$ mdadm --detail /dev/md0

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Jun 18 15:15:31 2022
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 2094080 (2045.00 MiB 2144.34 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 2094080 (2045.00 MiB 2144.34 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Feb 10 11:08:47 2024
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : AS1102T-29C0:0
              UUID : 8c8a1df8:da6ea8f9:1e1d2f61:a6978048
            Events : 871

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2
```

$$ mdadm --examine /dev/sda4

```
/dev/sda4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 28a37dd1:069d4a00:848af77e:d11cf15f
           Name : AS1102T-29C0:1
  Creation Time : Sat Jun 18 15:15:44 2022
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 967596032 sectors (461.39 GiB 495.41 GB)
     Array Size : 483798016 KiB (461.39 GiB 495.41 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=263912 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e237d8b7:cd97b14d:ab095b38:af3099cb

    Update Time : Sat Feb  3 12:40:15 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 2db3dfeb - correct
         Events : 0


   Device Role : spare
   Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

$ mdadm --assemble --scan

```
mdadm: Fail to create md0 when using /sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array, fallback to creation via node
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
$ mdadm --assemble --force
$mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda4
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sda4 to /dev/md0: Invalid argument
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from -1 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.
$mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Don't hesitate to ask for more !

Comment: If it's a former RAID1, there is no need for assemble, just copy the data from the remaining and still working RAID1 drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key issue is that `mdadm --examine /dev/sda4` shows:

`Device Role : spare`

This means that the surviving disks had some issues and was "semi-detached" from the array (ie: it was not on active duties anymore). This is confirmed by the warning `bad blocks present`.

**If you really need the data back, I strongly advise you to stop here and seek professional help.**

If, and only if, this is not an option, *and you are ready to accept total data loss if anything goes wrong*, you can try to entirely bypass the RAID array, directly mounting the inner filesystem with something as:

```
mkdir /mnt/sda4
mount -o ro,norecovery,offset=$((264192*512)) /dev/sda4 /mnt/sda4
```

Comment: You are my hero. I first copy my HDD to another HDD, just in case and try the command line you gave me on it and it worked. I was able to save it in clear and put it in the new NAS. I planned regular backup every month from now on. Thanks a lot